# How to use bootstrap mixin with LESS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less, less-mixins

I'm preparing the layout for page and have to use Bootstrap 3. I have a button with gradient, so I wanted to use Bootstrap mixin `#gradient.horizontal`:

```
background: #gradient.horizontal(@color-start,@color-end,0%,100%);
```

But I got parse error when running compilation task:

```
[13:21:24] { type: 'Parse',
filename: 'path_to_file.less',
index: 535,
line: 23,
callLine: NaN,
callExtract: undefined,
column: 18,
extract: 
  [ '      display: block;',
    '      background: #gradient.horizontal(@color-start,@color-end,0%,100%);',
    '      box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);' ],
message: 'Unrecognised input in file path_to_file.less line no. 23',
stack: undefined,
lineNumber: 23,
fileName: 'path_to_file.less',
name: 'Error',
showStack: false,
showProperties: true,
plugin: 'gulp-less',
__safety: { toString: [Function] } }
```

I'm using bootstrap-less v:3.3.8 and in main.less file I import whole bootstrap `@import "bootstrap/index";`

I would appreciate any hint how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found it... sorry for mess

It should be:

```
#gradient.horizontal(@color-start,@color-end,0%,100%);
```

without background: